# Rewrite a filter as shortcode (or something like that) to use anywhere in CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, shortcode

I have 2 CPT with relationship: `stfic`  and `stfic-child`.

`single-stfic.php` create book interview and table of contents (list of chapters from `stfic-child`) and `single-stfic-child.php` as chapter's content. Both of them linked to `stfic-manuscripts` as taxonomies.

Then I created a filter in `single-stfic.php` to create a table of contents for my fiction site (below).

So, how can I make it as a shortcode? Or make it as something simple to use anywhere?

I also added original `single-stfic.php` file content here: https://pastebin.com/LhVgK0AS

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'stfic-child',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'post_parent'       => 0,
    'stfic-manuscripts' => $termSlug
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $query->have_posts($post->ID) ) : $query->the_post();
    echo '<li><a href="'. get_permalink(). '">' .get_the_title() .'</a></li>';  
endwhile;

wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: There are some weird things in your code... You can remove the arg from `$query->have_posts( $post->ID )`. This method doesn't accept args. Also, your tax query in your `$args` is deprecated.

Comment: Then about how to make shortcode... I believe there are tons of tutorials everywhere about that... Reading https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API may be a good start. Then just put your query loop into the shortcode... Simple as that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your code simple and be able "to be used anywhere" is pretty subjective. Since you're writing code and you don't specify where you want your code to ultimately be used, the easiest thing to do would be to make it a function:
`function my_function() { ... }`

However, to make it a shortcode, there are some great examples on the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) that I use all the time when I want to make a shortcode:

```
function bartag_func( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo' => 'something',
        'bar' => 'something else',
    ), $atts );

    //Run whatever code I want to here...

    return $my_result;
}
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' ); //[bartag foo="foo-value"]
```

If you don't want any variables passed in, then you can remove the first block of code designed to extract the variables.

With shortcodes, you must `return` your result. Anything that is echoed/printed directly will end up in weird places on your page -- and not where you want it to. If a function you want to use wants to echo directly, use the output buffer to capture the data and put it into a string:

```
ob_start();
    //My Code
$result = ob_get_clean();
```

*Shortcode functions should be able to add and apply filters depending on what you are wanting to do, but it's worth noting that if you are using a shortcode/filter combination that WP uses (like filtering the content of a post in your shortcode function that is placed in the content of a post), you may get stuck in a filtering loop.*